# Bad state no element in Flutter Using FutureBuilder and Provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-futurebuilder

Using Provider and FutureBuilder, I just deleted data from database, it got removed at the same time, it shows a red screen with bad state no element. There is no problem to add data, do not show this problem.
Code is given below

stacktrace

```
ter (12519): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (12519): The following StateError was thrown building ViewNoteScreen(dirty, dependencies:
I/flutter (12519): [_ModalScopeStatus], state: _ViewNoteScreenState#f589b):
I/flutter (12519): Bad state: No element
I/flutter (12519): 
I/flutter (12519): The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter (12519):   ViewNoteScreen file:///C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/daily%2010/provider_note/lib/main.dart:21:46
I/flutter (12519):
I/flutter (12519): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (12519): #0      ListMixin.firstWhere (dart:collection/list.dart:148:5)
I/flutter (12519): #1      Providers.findById (package:provider_note/helper/provider.dart:14:19)
I/flutter (12519): #2      _ViewNoteScreenState.build (package:provider_note/screens/view_note.dart:21:35)
I/flutter (12519): #3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4663:28)
I/flutter (12519): #4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4546:15)
I/flutter (12519): #5      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4719:11)
I/flutter (12519): #6      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4262:5)
I/flutter (12519): #7      BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2667:33)
I/flutter (12519): #8      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:866:20)
I/flutter (12519): #9      RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:286:5)
I/flutter (12519): #10     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1117:15)
I/flutter (12519): #11     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1056:9)
I/flutter (12519): #12     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:972:5)
I/flutter (12519): #16     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:253:10)
I/flutter (12519): #17     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:211:3)
I/flutter (12519): (elided 3 frames from dart:async)
I/flutter (12519):
I/flutter (12519): ══════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: shouldn't `_items.remove(position);` be `_items.removeAt(position);` ?

Comment: not working.. I already checked. actually, it deletes the data but shows red screen with bad state no element.

Comment: Please show me the type of the `_items` variable.

Comment: You probably access an item which does not exist in the list. For example, accessing `_items[3]` while `_items` only has length < 2, or using `first`, `firstWhere`, `last`, `lastWhere` without supplying an `orElse` parameter. Now what you should do is using the `Find Usages` on the `_items` variable to see if you accidentally use it like I suggest.

Comment: actually, I think am not. I will show you more code..one minute

Comment: It shows when home.dart opens

Comment: I have updated the question with code

Comment: I see a bunch of `_items.firstWhere` statements in your code. Are you sure those do not cause the problem? If possible please post the stacktrace also.

Comment: I am not sure... what is happening.. okay.. i will post stacktrace also

Comment: stacktrace added

Comment: the line that causes the problem is `final selectedNote = provider.findById(id);` inside `_ViewNoteScreenState`. It is clearly stated in the stacktrace, you are using `firstWhere` to find the note with the specified `id`, but it doesn't exist. What you should do is using `indexWhere` to find the index of the note, and if it's >= 0, then the note exists.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`BadStateException` occurred when list don't contain the item and still someone searching for that

**Example:**

If `orElse` not defined in the code and the wrong item gets search which doesn't exist in the list then it shows `BadStateException`

```
 void main() {
      List<String> list = ['red', 'yellow', 'pink', 'blue'];
      var newList = list.firstWhere((element) => element.contains('green'));
      print(newList);
    }
```

**Output:**

```
Uncaught Error: Bad state: No element
```

**Solution:** Add orElse

```
 void main() {
      List<String> list = ['red', 'yellow', 'pink', 'blue'];
      var newList = list.firstWhere((element) => element.contains(''), 
          orElse: () => 'No matching color found');
      print(newList);
    }
```

**Output:**

```
No matching color found
```

Comment: @c49: see edited answer, if item is not available in list, then you need to handle it by adding orElse

Comment: yeah..found it.. but the problem is it is calling after deleting due to Consumer or Provider. How to avoid calling that?

Comment: Either add listen: false, but I think should be call, and to handle this you must return null, from method and handle this null inside widget, Ex: Don't show widget if its nulll

Comment: that's the problem, can't return null in findbyid

Comment: why? you can't return null

Comment: the container is due to can't return null in build methods.

Comment: This condition should in class from where you are calling ViewNoteScreen Widget, There you can add a null condition whether to show it or not.  I think this will work for you, could you please accept the answer.

Comment: That won't work. viewscreen is the child of the consumer. That's why viewscreen gets called automatically, when an item deleted. that's how it calls findbyid.

Comment: Either you have to find a way to stop calling ViewNoteScreen Widget, or show empty container inside it, both are fine.

Comment: I have tried all ways that I know, to stop calling ViewNoteScreen automatically. is showing empty container makes memory leak? because I think ViewNoteScreen is showing container behind the home screen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222439/discussion-between-jitsm555-and-c49).

Comment: same problem..however he solved it.. he says in comment...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62605192/flutter-bad-state-no-element

Comment: This is such a confusing error message.  Thank you for the fix.  (Just found myself back here again)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way for you is change your home to statefull widget and change this part of your code.

```
Navigator.pushNamed(
 context, ViewNoteScreen.routeName,
     arguments: notes.items[i].id).whenComplete(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
```